# Is the word "unsetup" valid in English?

Tags: meaning

I'm a software developer, and making a peer code review, I've encountered with the word **unsetup** used in the context to uninitialize some stuff. I was wondering if this is an actual word in English, or it is just an invention.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find the word in any dictionaries? Have you encountered it *more than once*, from otherwise "competent" speakers?

Comment: The "un-" prefix functions independently in English. Not every possible use is listed in dictionaries, because so many verbs and adjectives can potentially take "un-" that it would blow up the U section disproportionately to list them all. Dictionaries are simple word lists and do not have good coverage of the creative possibilities of language morphology, for good reasons. So the idea that only those words are legitimate which appear in dictionaries is very parochial.

Comment: "Unsetup" is just as valid as "uninitialize."

Answer (score 6):

Normally the opposite of *a set-up* is *a tear-down*.

Comment: And this is used in computing, by those who are literate. Set up the session/connection/object framework/whatever. Then, tear it down.

Comment: Personally, I would say you _destroy_ a session/connection/object when you reverse the act of initialising it (‘unsetup’ it). I have never seen anyone use the term “tearing down a session”, but `session.destroy()` and its derived phrasing is extremely common.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Setup–teardown is the standard terminology in software testing frameworks. Construction–destruction and initialization–finalization are other common terms for the same concept in other contexts.

Comment: For frameworks, I agree (which is why I didn't include that it the list). I wouldn't use it for sessions, connections, or objects, though, just like I wouldn't use construction/destruction of a session, but of an object. For connections, I would use initialise/finalise (or set up/destroy). My point was just that teardown is not the standard antonym to setup in all coding respects.

Comment: Hm, in a context where _teardown_ isn't appropriate, I probably wouldn't use _setup._ For a session, I'd probably use _startup/shutdown._

Comment: @BraddSzonye I also use `setup` with `cleanup`. I like the parallelism :) tchrist, +1!

Answer (score 5):

While creating a new word is perfectly OK, and quite common in technology in particular, **unsetup** is not an existing word in current common use.

Answer (score 3):

*Unsetup* as an adjective, meaning 'not (yet) assembled', would be comprehensible.  You appear to want a verb the opposite of *set up*, and the problem there is that it has no opposite in normal parlance, so there is no word for it. Similarly, there is an adjective *uncreated*, but no word **uncreate* (though *destroy* does the job most of the time).

Answer (score 0):

**Un** is a prefix when placed in front of *some* nouns, adverbs, participles and adjectives means; "not", "the opposite to" and "contrary to"

Unhappy = *not happy*; uncertain = *not certain*; unlucky = *not lucky*; unhelpful = *not helpful* etc.

Unsetup (if it existed)= *not setup*. Which is nonsensical, if you think about it. To setup means

> the act or process of installing (computer software or hardware)

Once a computer programme is setup it cannot revert to *not setup* The programme can be *on* or *off*, it can be *working* or *broken* but you cannot create the opposite of the noun, *setup*, by adding the prefix, un. You need a different word.

Comment: _Un-_ does not mean ‘not’ when prefixed to verbs. ‘To undo’ does not mean ‘not to do’. Rather, it means ‘reverse the doing and cancel it out’. Similarly, ‘unsetup’ means ‘void the setup that has been performed’. The sense of ‘setup’ used here is not quite the same as what you quote; the notion of ‘un-setupping’ does make sense here, the things set up can be reverted to a _not set up_ state.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet   http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/un?showCookiePolicy=true and http://www.thefreedictionary.com/un- and http://www.ask.com/question/what-does-the-prefix-un-mean ( I could go on) all confirm that "un" as a prefix means "not" when placed in front of adjectives, nouns etc. Among the examples I cited, none are verbs. SETUP (one word) instead is a noun according to: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/setup and http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/setup

Comment: But, I was wrong to say: "you cannot create the opposite of setting something up"  I should have phrased the concept differently.

Comment: I'm convinced, however, that the asker here is using it as a verb (adding _un-_ to the phrase ‘set up’ would presumably univerbate it), since that makes most sense, and since he writes “in the context _to uninitialize_ some stuff”.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty convinced too. That's why I've explained as simply as possible, *why* a word such as, unsetup, cannot exist and does not exist. If the definition of setup is the one found in dictionaries then he needs a different word to convey the opposite meaning. If instead he wants or uses it as a verb then that's up to him.

Comment: If @JanusBahsJacquet you believe the OP is justified to use "unsetup" as implied by your comments, I suggest that you write and post your answer to the OP. Maybe he will accept it!

Comment: That wasn’t actually quite the intended implication. I’m a bit on the fence about whether I’d consider ‘to unsetup’ valid or not. I just wanted to clarify some details in your answer. :-)